# Does time taken and a poor grade for a PHD in Germany destroy chances for a post doc?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, supervision, germany, grades

I  come from a violent country that gives me no hope for the future. I cannot go back. My supervisor has more than 30 students, did not read my chapters, and insisted that I give in the first draft as final. The second supervisor, the expert on the subject, resents that the first supervisor will get all the credit. So neither helped. Refused to read drafts. The defense was full of questions that a reading of the first draft would have easily fixed. There was no support from the institution and I ended up with an average grade of cum laude after more than a decade of effort. All on my dime. Odd jobs. The reason I delayed was that my home country is hell and my family depends on me.
I am so desperate that I d rather do a second Ph.D. than go home. I don t know if they will give me recommendations for a postdoc.
Any solutions to get out of this? I mean can I get a postdoc with lukewarm recommendations? I have a sterling academic record, publications though a bit dated, and I truly think this grade is unfair.

Comment: "The problem is finding a non-academic job, I believe, means that I need to have a high salary" - what do you mean? You need a high salary? Is that essential? Why not prove yourself and develop your salary? US may not care about the 'cum laude', but they will care about publications, so the latter is more of an issue there.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs It's about getting a visa, I assume. EU regulations on that should be public. (Though I don't think it is astronomically high - should be possible to get with a PhD.)  EDIT: 56800 in Germany.  I'd say high for the 1st job but not impossible.

Comment: Yes, exactly to get a job outside academics there is a high threshold. Right now I d be happy to work for a decent anything but that wont gets me permanent residence unless it is connected to academics. Essentially I should show a job that requires a PhD.

Comment: Can you shorten this post to be only about the actual question you have? It seems like the last line is what you actually care about, but I'm not sure.

Comment: In the US, the grades (and "cum laude") will mean little. It is the possession of a doctorate and letters of recommendation that will mean more.

Comment: @Buffy: In Germany, PhD "grades" are undergoing inflation, depending on the subject area, "cum laude" can indicate a very mediocre thesis evaluation. That also might imply unwillingness of the supervisor to provide a good LoR.

Comment: @Peter. I'd be much more worried about letters for positions in the US. And even more about whether skill match any advertised position.

Comment: Also, the 56.800 mark does not hold for STEM or medical degree holders, in that case it's 44.304 Euros which is very achievable depending on Bundesland. EDIT: nvm, that doesn't seem to apply to the OP.

Comment: My subject is interdisciplinary and I really doubt I would get a job that pays 44, 304 euros per year. That s why I am really worried. The committee said that the work was good but that procedural norms were not followed. Frankly, if they had read the first draft once over the criticism could easily have been addressed, but they refused to.

Comment: @user78397: Is the subject one of "mathematics, computer science, natural sciences or technology"? If so I don't see a problem, if you get a job in e.g. Munich as a PhD graduate in one of those areas it's absolutely unthinkable that you will be paid less than 50.000 Euros a year. For someone with a PhD the limit might actually be even lower but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: @Buffy At least in math/physics, a grade below "magna cum laude" points to a  mediocre thesis (but this might be very different in other fields, grading standards at least in undergrad e.g. differ vastly!).  If everything else were fine (CV, publications, letters), no issue at all, but I don't think this would happen - for a bad grade, it is clear that you advisor was negative about your work, so if they were to write a strong letter, they would be dishonest in their letter.

Comment: @user151413 Good letters and mediocre thesis seem kind of mutual exclusive though.

Comment: Related, particularly for a German context: [I believe my PhD dissertation was unfairly graded too low (cum laude): what should I do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/139502/68109).

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Sure, that's my point: If you have a bad PhD grade at least in math/physics in Germany, you *will* have difficulties finding a postdoc, because you won't get a strong letter from your advisor (or the absence of a letter from the advisor will point towards the bad grade).

Comment: In the rest of the world, nobody cares about the grade of the PhD -- just about the three letters. It took me till the question linked to two comments up before I understood what my own grade actually meant. Nobody has ever asked me about my grade in my 18 years in the US and I don't think anyone has cared at all.

Comment: There are different regulations for getting a work visa after finishing a course of study in Germany (which includes PhDs). In particular there is no salary requirement, but it has to match to your degree. That does not mean you can only take jobs in academia though, anything requiring a university degree in your field should do. (E.g. math PhD -> Insurance company is an example I know of). There is also the possibility to become self-employed in something related to your field. Your university should have an international office who should know more details, so you should talk to them.

Comment: @Wolfgang Of course no-one would ask for it - but if you apply in Germany and you got a "rite", I'd recommend to not mention the grade in the application, say, in math.  For me, this would be a red flag.

Comment: It is a multi disciplinary social science PhD. I was the topper of the Master course and that's why I got it.. I deeply regret taking it. With average recommendation is it possible to get a post doc if my idea is good? I can ask for recommendations but they did not even read it. They refused to

Comment: @user151413 Maybe with a "rite", but OP did not get a "rite"; they got a "cum laude", which is not actively a bad grade. Even in Germany (I am German, just for the record), what matters more is good ideas, good recommendations, good publications. In the absence of an actively bad (rite) or exceptional (summa) grade, that's what every candidate is rated by.

Comment: @Wolfgang Well, there is "summa cum laude", "magna cum laude", "cum laude", and "rite".  I think the typical grade is a "magna cum laude", with the frequency of the "summa" depending on the place (most places I know try to decrease the number of summas).  So I'd say a "cum laude" is a pointer that something didn't go quite well, though maybe not bad as it could have gone.  As I said, I'd be surprised if someone got a strong letter from their advisor after receiving a "cum laude" in math or physics; other fields might well differ.